# New to GitHub - New repository and Questions

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Im new to github and Im trying to push some files to my repository. But I have the **'main'** branch with the README file but *all my file*s are being pushed to the new **'master'** branch added using GIT bash.
So when somebody enters this repository it will just see the main branch with a README file, and all the project files will be at the *master* branch.
Is there a problem with it?
I hope I made myself clear.
Also if you have any tips for this newbie user, they are all welcome.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Github* recently decided to rename all its main branches from **master** to **main** by default. 
*Git Bash* still uses *master* as the default main branch. To simply fix the problem, you can rename your branch from *master* to *main* on *Git Bash* using the following command: 
`$ git branch -M main` 
(This command allows you to rename the current branch in which you are working)

So, after deleting the *master* *branch* on *Github* and applying the command suggested above, push your code again: you will now have only one main branch called *main* on both *Github* and *Git Bash*.

Comment: @BenjaF accepting answers is also a way to say *"Thank you"*